# Retrieve data whose Date between start and end date is between today and after ten day in rails or sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to retrieve  data whose Date between start and end date is between today and after ten day.I'm doing it in rails but even if i get the query in MySQL i can convert it to rails active record.

Something like this one :

```
select * from users where( between users.from and users.to =  between '2012-11-25 11:52:33' and '2012-12-05 11:52:33')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval (a, b) overlaps with (c, d) iff a < d and b > c. Also, the `curdate()` function returns the current date ("today"). To calculate the date ten days into the future you can use `+ interval 10 day`.

Combining these bits of information you get:

```
select ... where users.to > curdate() 
and users.from < curdate() + interval 10 day
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Soory but this will not work if my start date is before today and end date is after say 11 days

Comment: Please rephrase the question. If start date is before today and end date is after say 11 days, then start and end date are *not* between today and after ten day, which is what you asked.

Comment: Well it should still fetch the data as its dates still exists in today and after 10 days.Btw i'm sorry if my way of asking is wrong.

Comment: So the condition is really if the interval (from, to) overlaps with (today, today+10 days)? See update.

Answer (score 0):

Follwing is the logic snippet not the exact code though. Please try.

```
select * from users 
where users.fromDate between '2012-11-25 11:52:33' and '2012-12-05 11:52:33'
and users.toDate between '2012-11-25 11:52:33' and '2012-12-05 11:52:33';
```

Check the following sample code in * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85433/1) as well

**EDITING AS PER YOUR QUESTION'S REPHRASING..**

Guess you are better off with,

```
where users.from between users.from and users.from + interval 10day
and users.to <= user.from + interval 10 day
```

That means, your `from date` can be anything (today, yesterday, one month back, two years to future...). Hence your `to-date` will be validated against any date that is 10 days interval from the above `from-date`

Hope it makes sense... but again, Joni's answers fills for your today's consition. :)

Comment: Joni's code is more beautiful I notice and clean - using efficient commands for better performance. He is trying to tell you any of your start/end date within 10 days interval current date (for e.g. today) . Mine is the elaborated basic view that you wanted ;)

Comment: This condition will fail if my start date is before today and end date is after say 11 days.

Comment: Surely, this is not dynamic. Thats why I said Joni's code is beautiful and efficient :)